# How to add a Method in TimeDuration that Time can deal with it?

Tags: ruby

i have a [class TimeDuration (gist)](https://gist.github.com/addisaden/4cd682f5415059eac0ae) and i can deal with simple durations.

```
# Basic work:

ten_hours = TimeDuration.new("10 hours")
# => #<TimeDuration:0x936587c @duration=36000>

Time.now
# => 2013-09-13 09:12:07 +0200

ten_hours + Time.now
# => 2013-09-13 19:12:30 +0200

ten_hours + ten_hours + Time.now
=> 2013-09-14 05:12:44 +0200
```

But one doesnt work :( :

```
 Time.now + ten_hours
 # TypeError: can't convert TimeDuration into an exact number
 # in `+'
```

Is there a way to create a method in TimeDuration, that this works? I don't want to manipulate the Time-Class :)

Thank you

Comment: `Time.now + ten_hours.duration` should work

Comment: As a reference: ActiveSupport does similar things with `ActiveSupport::Duration`. They decided to [patch time](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef5d85709d346e55827e88f53430a2cbe1e5fb9e/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb#L217).

Comment: But when i use a method the "magic" is away ... in the usage there should be no change and for the user trivial how to use it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`time + numeric → time`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-2B)

> Addition — Adds some number of seconds (possibly fractional) to time and returns that value as a new Time object.

`Time.now + ten_hours` does not work,as it needs *numeric* value,not the object. In your case `ten_hours` is an instance of `TimeDuration` class.

The below will work :

```
ten_hours = TimeDuration.new("10 hours")
Time.now + ten_hours.duration
# => 2013-09-13 23:50:35 +0530
```

Comment: Hmm do you know how i can make my TimeDuration as Numeric? with include? Is there a magic method like for Enumerable <=>?

Comment: @addisaden But what you are looking for your code have that. I think. Probably I couldn't get you.

Comment: "Time.now + five_minutes + ten_minutes" should be the same as "five_minutes + ten_minutes + Time.now" :)

Comment: @addisaden why you are not interested with `five_minutes.duration` ? It seems good to me.. :)

Comment: ^^ i know. Maybe i want just the perfect way. The solution i didnt expected ^^…